# How to work with responsive 'vh' sizes without the page "jumping" when scrolling in chrome browsers or other browsers with a URL bar

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, responsive-design

I'm working on a responsive website and I'm so frustrated with finding a solution for this one.

this is the basic structure:

[image]

[image]

I used 'vh' sizes and when ever the URL bar slides up - the page changes the sizes of the elements and kinda "jumps", which makes a bad user experience especially when reading.

I changed the size of the second part (orange) to 'em's because I thought maybe it will not "jump"  so at least where there are texts this will not happen - and I was wrong. it's still happening.

What I'm trying to get to is to make the first part (in baby-blue) opened on all of the screen no matter what screen size is displaying the page (but without making it "jump").

I'm very frustrated finding a solution to responsive pages, can you please help me solve this, or help me with some reading material that will help me solve this ?

Note: I found some codes to add that should remove the URL bars from iPhones and it didn't work :I

Comment: "Removing the url bars" ? Are you trying to make it fullscreen? Because vh is viewportheight and relates to the section INSIDE the browser border.

Comment: You _might_ have to try setting the height using javascript on page load/resize. It's a hacky solution, but it guarantees that the height of the element won't change when the address bar disappears.

Comment: @ChristianVarga - Hi, do you have a link to somewhere that explanes how and what I can do with javascript in this case? or suggest some keywords to search on google ?

Comment: @noel - as you see, it is a full screen. I know..

Comment: @Hatul So you want to hide the url bar all the time? Or is your issue that it jumps when the visible bar is shrinking?

Comment: Both are good. 
If I have an option to hide the URL bar (which I don't, at chrome at least..) without changing anything with my current CSS code - awesome! Using other methods that will display my page as described in my main post will be good too.

Answer (score 0):

Since you've tagged Javascript/jQuery I'd suggest assigning the height by getting the height the specific element (eg: window, document or viewport) you want.  [A good comparison can be found here](http://ryanve.com/lab/dimensions/).  From the looks of it, you might want `window.outerHeight` which may account for what's "under" the URL bar.  On my desktop, it's the only value that's different from the rest but on mobile other values may be different as well.

```
document.querySelectorAll(".whatever").style.height=window.outerHeight;
```